# python append to new line in file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, line

I'm trying to append text to a new line in python, but it keeps adding it directly on the same line as which the last sentence ends. I have tried adding '\n' but it produces two empty lines. For example;

```
text = 'hello there'

with open('hello.txt', 'ab') as temp_file:
    temp_file.write('\n' + text)
```

If I run the above 3 times I get;

```
# empty line
# empty line      
hello there
hello there
hello there
```

Is there a way to append text to the next new line, without leaving any empty lines? I know I could write another `with open` function to strip empty lines, but wanted to see if there was a more cleaner, compact way of doing it. Thanks.

Comment: are you using windows? and which editor are you using to view your result?

Comment: Have you tried adding the newline after `text` like `temp_file.write(text + '\n')`?  That would be most similar to the behavior of the `print` function/statement.

Comment: that's a python 2 question, doesn't work in python 3. I have only 1 empty line, then the text, as expected. What do you want to achieve exactly? what is the output you're expecting after, say, 3 calls?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am using Linux (centos 7.2) and using vim as my editor. Also am using python 2.7

Comment: @BrianCain I tried that, but this time it added one extra line instead at the top.

Comment: @user1165419, it shouldn't, you must have edited the file with an editor instead of removing the file first.  `vim` likely has this behavior by default, saving files with nothing less than a newline when the buffer appears empty.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm trying to add a SSL certificate and CA bundle in one file (as required for nginx). Any empty lines I believe could cause nginx  to fail when restarted. So that's why I need the cert/ca in one file, without any empty lines.

Comment: @BrianCain You're right. I was doing `echo > hello.txt` and then trying it again on the same file. This time I removed/added the file from scratch and it works. Thanks!

Comment: okay, then why do you add newlines (empty lines) at the beginning of your file? Can you show us how you would like the file after 3 runs? (not in the comments, [edit] your question please)

Answer (score -2):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('echo "' + YOURTEXT + '" >> hello.txt',shell=True)
```

foolproof